# Responsive PHP header with three divs

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm a student and new to coding. I am attempting to build a website for my boss as a pet project. I am attempting to develop a responsive header with a background image overlaid with three transparent divs where I shall put three links. Being that I am working with WordPress and using a free theme, I must do most of this through PHP. However, I have also worked with some CSS in the attempt to make the header work. The website I am attempting to build is located here:

http://cmheatingcooling.newcalling.org

The CSS code is as follows:

```
.header-section{

min-height: 35vh;
min-width: 150vh;

background:url('http://cmheatingcooling.newcalling.org/wp-
content/uploads/2017/05/cropped-CandM.jpg');
background-size: cover;
background-size: 100% 100%;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The dotted box represents one of the divs which I am attempting to insert within the header section of the PHP code. The div code is as follows:

```
<?php 
echo " <div style=\"width: 280px; height: 200px; border: 2px dashed #000000;  
display:inline-block; position: relative; top: 50%; bottom: 50%; right: 0%; 
left: 150%; padding: 3px; margin: 5px\">"; 
?>
```

Any help anyone can offer me on this would be huge. At this point, I feel like I'm wondering around in the dark. If I am not clear enough, please be patient, as it is most likely due to a lack of expertise, not a lack of motivation to solve my problem or to be helpful to those who are helping me.

Thank you.

Comment: You need to slice out this image `(http://cmheatingcooling.newcalling.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/cropped-CandM.jpg)` propely into 4 pieces. 1- Logo, 2- Background for logo, 3- Chicken/cartoon, 4- Background for chicken/cartoon. This is a beginner approach. You can also do this using CSS, All you need is two images: 1 for logo and other for chicken/cartoon character.

Comment: seems php script error in your site

Comment: your html script is not valid `<div id="div_one" style:="" width:="" 280px;="" height:="" 200px;="" border:="" 2px="" dashed="" #000000;="" display:inline-block;="" position:="" relative;="" top:="" 50%;="" bottom:="" right:="" 0%;="" left:="" 150%;="" padding:="" 3px;="" margin:="" 5px\;"=""></div>
`

Comment: What is problem exactly and where are those _ three transparent divs_? I don't see them within the `header-section` div.